# How to track down elements causing horizontal scroll on a web page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system, css-grid

As developing responsible web pages using different grid systems, I sometimes face the issue that certain elements overflow, have problematic sizes / paddings / margins thus making the page horizontally scrollable.

I found it sometimes with the point & click (select element tool in chrome) hard to track these elements down, since - don't know why - they sometimes are not selectable.

How could one quickly identify misbehaving elements?

Comment: You can sometimes spot overlapping elements by pressing CTRL+A to select everything. Also you could use the browsers developer console and delete sections of code until the horizontal bar is removed to tracks down the problem element. Matyas solution below is quite clever though, I will be sure to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to iterate through all elements and print them to the `console` if their `width` is bigger than that of the `window`.

In chrome, **click**ing on these elements would **highlight** them **on the page** and show them in the `DOM` explorer

The code:

```js
// retrieve all elements
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var bigElements = 
  // use the filter function to filter get only elements you need
  Array.prototype.filter.call(
    allElements, 
               // compares occupied width with window width
    element => element.getBoundingClientRect().width > window.innerWidth
  );

// print resulting elements
bigElements.forEach(element => console.log(element));
if (!bigElements.length) console.log('Yaay! All elements fit. ');
```

To get rid of horizontal scrolling one shall analyze the layouting of each component and modify it, until this snippet prints no elements

Comment: This is quite neat, but doesn't solve the problem really - it only shows single elements which width exceeds the window width (obviously) but the problem may be more complex (groups of elements, margins for instance).